# Solving $x-\ln(x) = y$ for $x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Suppose I have an equation: $$x-\ln(x) = y$$ How would I rearrange this to make $x$ the subject of the formula?

Is there a trick for such equations?

Comment: [WolframAlpha gives $x=-W(-e^{-y})$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+solve+y%3Dx-logx+for+x).  Are you familiar with the product log or Lambert W function?

Comment: @PhysicsStudent Essentially, there is no 'easy' way to make $x$ the subject of this equation. As Andrew Chin has noted, we have to use the special function $W$ that is the inverse of $f(x)=xe^x$. Since $f$ is not one-to-one, $W$ is not a 'function' in the strict sense of the word. In addition to these problems, there is no easy to way to actually compute what $W(x)$ is—although in certain cases we can use Taylor series. Read more about the Lambert W function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function])